# How to test for "air" in Hotbar using /execute command

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How do I test for Air in Slot 9? with the `/execute` command?

I've came up with this so far but it doesn't work

```
/execute if entity @a[nbt={Inventory:[{Slot:8b,id:"minecraft:air"}]}] run give @a minecraft:stick
```

What did I do wrong?

I'm playing version 1.15

Answer (score 3):

The **Inventory** array only contains slots with items in them. If the slot is empty, it is removed from the array.

You can observe this by running `/data get entity @s Inventory`. For example, if you had an apple in the first slot of your Hotbar and you run the command, the following output would be displayed.

```
[{Slot:0b,id:"minecraft:apple",Count:1b}]
```

^ as you can see, only populated slots are displayed.

You can detect an empty slot by testing if it has data. Example:

```
/execute if data entity @s Inventory[{Slot:0b}]
```

^ this command will return either 1 or 0 depending on whether or not the specified slot has any data.

Now store the output of this test into a scoreboard objective so you can actually use it:

```
/execute store result score @s <obj> run execute if data entity @s Inventory[{Slot:0b}]
```

and finally, you can now do something like `/execute if score @s <obj> matches 1 run say item detected!`

Comment: "run execute" is never needed. And you can just tag the player if that data exists. But the general idea is good!